# Why cant i assign a function to function pointer?

Tags: c++

While doing my homework i decided to use function pointer as a callback function. I am not going to post the whole homework here as it is too large. Here i wrote small test code to illustrate the error i am getting.

```
#include <iostream>

void function()
{
    std::cout << "test";
}

int main()
{
    void* functionPtr(int) = function;
    functionPtr();
}
```

I am getting error C2059:  syntax error: '=' here `void* functionPtr(int) = function;`. If i hower my mouse over = sign it says next: "function functionPtr cannot be initialized". If i change that to ...

```
    void* functionPtr();
    functionPtr = function;
```

...i will be getting error C2659:  '=': function as left operand.
Am i using function pointers wrong way? 
I use Visual Studio 2019 btw.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: This is a function declaration, not a function pointer declaration.

Comment: Please don't fix the code in the question after getting an answer. It invalidates the answers you got, and might confuse future readers.

Comment: yep, that int isnt supposed to be there. But removing it doesnt fix the problem.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: okay i got it. I changed the post to the original.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't the right syntax. You declare a function, not a function pointer.

Here's how a function pointer is declared:

```
void(*functionPtr)(int);
```

As you noticed, the star is beside the name. If there is no parenthesis, the star will apply to the return type and not the name.

Or with a trailing return type:

```
auto(*functionPtr)(int) -> void;
```

Also, your function called `function` don't take an int as parameter. So it should be like this:

```
void(*functionPtr)() = function;
```

Comment: Could cut out even a little more and do `auto functionPtr = &function;` (but that may be syntactically further from the problem faced by the OP).

Answer (score 4):

You got the types wrong. There is no `int` parameter for in `function` and you missed a `*`. Your declare `functionPtr` as a function. For a function pointer you need:

```
void(*functionPtr)() = function;
  // ^--- "pointer to function"
```

However, since C++11, `using` function pointers got much simpler, as you can do

```
using functionPtrType = void(*)();
functionPtrType p = function;
```

Or

```
using functionPtrType = decltype(&function);
functionPtrType p = function;
```

which has a tiny disadvantage of not making it obvious that a function pointer is involved. The advantage is that it wont break when you change the signature of `function`.

On the other hand, once you use `decltype` (and you do not need the type of the function pointer elsewhere) you can as well shorten it to:

```
 decltype(&function) functionPtr = function;
```

Eventually, this is already avoiding so much to spell out the type that you can simply use `auto`:

```
 auto functionPtr = &function;
```

Answer (score 3):

To create a pointer to a function, you need to use parentheses to override the normal binding of the `*`. `void *f()` means `f` is a function returning a pointer to void. To instead get a pointer to a function returning void, you need `void (*f)();`

So in your case, the code would look something like `void (*functionPtr)() = function;`